# Can you say Method A respects the privacy?

Tags: word-usage

I have the following sentence and I need your help:

"Moreover, Method A **respects** the privacy of the residents"

This Method A is an optimization method that controlls flexible electrical loads in buildings without collecting personal data.

Can I use 'respects' in this context? Another option would be to say '... does not infringe on the privacy...' or 'preserves the privacy...'

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Why is *respect* **not** an appropriate verb here, any less than *preserve* or *infringe*?

Comment: Thanks Andrew Leach for your answer. I have not read the word 'respect' that often for in such a context about algorithms. In contrast, I have read the other words quite a few times. As I do not want to repete the other words so often, I wanted to use another word. This is why I asked this question. But according to your point of view the word 'respects' is suitable, right?